# How to formulate and simplify weighted differential entropy for Gaussian random variables?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy, gaussian

**Differential entropy** of a single random variable $X$ is

$$h(X) = -\int f(x_i) \ln f(x_i) \hspace{1mm} dx_i$$
The **weighted differential entropy** of $N$ different variables, each with their own differential entropy and uniquely assigned weight, contained in vectors $\boldsymbol w$ and $\boldsymbol h$, is the weighted sum
$$\boldsymbol w ^\top \boldsymbol{h} =-\Sigma_{i=1}^N w_i \int f(x_i) \ln f(x_i) \hspace{1mm} dx_i$$

In the case of a single **Gaussian variable**, differential entropy has a closed-form analytical solution, being a function of its variance, $\sigma_i^2$:
$$h = \frac{1}{2} \ln\left(2\pi e\sigma_i^2\right)$$

What then is a simplified form of **weighted Gaussian entropy**? Here is a start to my guess, which I am asking help to simplify, but at the same time open to analytical solutions for that compactly express the same quantity using *multivariate input* instead, i.e. the covariance matrix rather than individual $\sigma_i$'s.
\begin{align}&= \Sigma_{i=1}^N \left\{ w_i \times \frac{1}{2} \ln\left(2\pi e\sigma_i^2\right)\right\}_{i=1}^N\\
&= ?\end{align}

Comment: you should write $f_{i}(x)$ rather than $f(x_{i})$. And also, there is no exponential in the entropy.

Comment: Apart from that you can rewrite it e.g. as $\ln\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2\pi\sigma_{i})^{w_{i}/2}\right)$ which is not looking more pleasent, though.

Comment: or if that's more pleasing as $\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln(2\pi)|w|+\sum w_{i}\ln(\sigma_{i})\right)$ where $|w|$ denotes the sum of the weights.

Comment: Norwich (2003) shows that there is an exponential in Gaussian entropy. I just made the mistake of exponentiating $\sigma$ when in fact it only has to be multiplied by $e$: https://www.biopsychology.org/norwich/isp/chap8.pdf

Comment: Then you get for instance (since I also forgot the square on sigma) $\frac{|w|}{2}(\ln(2\pi)+1)+\sum w_{i}\ln(\sigma_{i})$.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can certainly rewrite it in vectorized form as $\frac{1}{2}w^T \ln(2\pi e\sigma^2)$ where the log is applied elementwise. Alternatively, you can write $\frac{1}{2}v^T \ln(2\pi e\Sigma)v$ where $v=\sqrt{w}$ and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with $\sigma^2$ on the diagonal, assuming the weights are nonnegative. The last one extends to the case where $\Sigma$ is not diagonal, but does it make sense? Maybe. I don't have time to find out.